# How to compare and take non-duplicate text in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
coalesce(case when main_parse_user.bio is distinct from EXCLUDED.bio
      and EXCLUDED.bio is not null 
     then concat(trim(main_parse_user.bio), ' ', trim(EXCLUDED.bio)) 
     else main_parse_user.bio end)
```

there is a code that takes and adds new data to an existing column

But I need to make sure that at first the code compares and enters only those words that are unique

EXAMPLE

```
  db
ID  NAME
1   qwerty

  input

ID NAME
1  qwerty new


  output
ID NAME
1  qwerty | new
```

you can do this in postgresql

Comment: Please update your question a little, I fail to really understand what is you want to achieve. Where is the list of words coming from? Comparing to what you want to compare uniqueness of words? What should happen to words which are not unique?

Comment: @bracko I have corrected!
And I would like to add.
There is a base in which the word ```qwerty``` is written and there is a match with the id and in case of a conflict it must compare the two texts.
The word ```qwerty new``` is entered and the database with this id already contains the word ```qwerty``` , but the word ```new``` is not there
And now I need the algorithm to pull out the word ```new``` and insert it into the database and the output should be ```qwerty | new```